# Resharper - turn off solution wide analysis

Tags: resharper

I want to turn it off completely and not get any solution-wide hints. I only see where I can pause I but can't find an answer for turning it off.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In Resharper 5.1, turn it off by unchecking the 'Analyze errors in whole solution' under ReSharper->Options->Code Inspection->Settings

[image]

You can also turn it off by right clicking on the green analysis circle (bottom right of Visual Studio) and select 'Analyse Errors in Solution'.

Comment: That did it! Not sure how I missed that... Thanks!

Comment: After changing the setting you can click on `Save To` -> `This computer` so that it becomes default option for new/opened solutions.

Answer (score 5):

In the tool window for Solution-wide analysis:

[image: image of R# solution-side analysis]

the ⑪ button pauses, as you have found; **the button to the *left* of that (the first button in that toolbar) turns off SWA**.

Comment: I believe the OP found the pause button, they wanted to know how to turn it of completely

Comment: @Piers ...which is what the first button does

Comment: ah, true, you can also get to this by right clicking the green analysis circle (at bottom right of VS) and select 'Analyse Errors in Solution'