# Resharper is not identifying not used members of an interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

When a method is declared in an interface and implemented in a class, but is not called anywhere in the project, Resharper does not detect it as an unused member.

I have to clean a project and delete these kind of members, how do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: you should give the minimum code to reproduce the error along with your question.

Comment: Hello, there is no error, this is a question about how Resharper function

Comment: Is SWEA (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Solution-Wide_Analysis.html) enabled for the solution? If no, enable it and in case a method is not used anywhere, ReSharper will show you a suggestion about that for the method in the interface.

Comment: Thank you, I have activated that option and Resharper list All the members that are not referenced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, I have activated the Option  'Analyze errors in whole solution'   .and Resharper list All the members that are not referenced.

[Resharper - turn off solution wide analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287765/resharper-turn-off-solution-wide-analysis)