# identify classes referencing unnecessary interfaces

Tags: c#

I have inherited an application in which a "God" (hundreds of methods) interface is used as a base class/interface for many other interfaces.  These interfaces are then implemented in many classes.  A lot of the classes that implement these interfaces don't use any of the methods in the base interface.  Is there a plugin or some tool that can identify if these classes are using none of the base interface methods so I can then remove the base interface implementation from the child interfaces?

Comment: Resharper ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646174/resharper-find-all-unused-classes & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945009/resharper-is-not-identifying-not-used-members-of-an-interface & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245963/find-unused-code

Comment: If you are using visual studio shift+f11 when the coursor is on the name of the method should show all the references of that method